# VBA - New Item on Two Column Value Change

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have eight columns of data. There are 500 rows. They are sorted by columns a and then b.

So it looks like this:

```
1111|1536|Data...
1111|1536|Data...
1111|1537|Data...
1112|1536|Data...
1112|1536|Data...
1112|1536|Data...
1112|1536|Data...
1112|1536|Data...
1112|1537|Data...
```

I'm having trouble writing code that in a ninth column starts renumbering the rows after the combination of columns a and b changes to something different. So I'd like it to look like this:

```
Item 1|1111|1536|Data...
Item 2|1111|1536|Data...
Item 1|1111|1537|Data...
Item 1|1112|1536|Data...
Item 2|1112|1536|Data...
Item 3|1112|1536|Data...
Item 4|1112|1536|Data...
Item 1|1112|1537|Data...
Item 2|1112|1537|Data...
```

I can't aggregate based on only these two columns because all eight create a unique combination of data and I need to preserve that combination.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used:

```
Sub Item()
Dim ItemVar As String
Dim ColAVar As String
Dim ColBVar As String
Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer

ItemVar = "Item "
n = 1

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert
ActiveCell.Value = ItemVar & CStr(n)

For i = 1 To 499
    ColAVar = ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Value
    ColBVar = ActiveCell.Offset(0,2).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    IF ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Value = ColAVar And ActiveCell.Offset(0,2).Value = ColBVar Then
        n = n + 1
    ELSE
        n = 1
    End If

    ActiveCell.Value = ItemVar & CStr(n)
Next i
End Sub
```